# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of Undefined

Tags: javascript

So, I was making a progress bar where it shows the amount of checkboxes checked. But there was an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of Undefined." I kept trying everything but the error was still there. Here is my JS file:

```
function updateProgress() {
      var i = 0;
      var checkAmt = 0;
      var checkedAmt = 0;
      while (i <= document.getElementsByClassName("gun-check").length) {
      if (document.getElementsByClassName("gun-check")[i].checked == "true") {
             checkAmt = checkAmt + 1;
        } 
        i = i + 1;
      }
    document.getElementById("progress-fill").style.width = (100 / 31) * checkAmt + "%";
    if ((100 / 31) * checkAmt > 5) {
        document.getElementById("progress-text").innerHTML = (100 / 31) * checkAmt + "%"; 
    }
}
```

Please help!

Comment: can u paste your HTML also

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("gun-check")[i].checked == "true"` should be `document.getElementsByClassName("gun-check")[i].checked === true` (boolean).

Comment: Huy Nguyen - I tried that.

Comment: Yeap, but you have 1 case wrong, because your loop `from 0 to i <=document.getElementsByClassName("gun-check").length`, it's should be `i < `, or if you want use `i <=`, `var i` should count from 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when `i` equals `document.getElementsByClassName("gun-check").length`, the index will be out of bounds.

Change this line:

```
while (i <= document.getElementsByClassName("gun-check").length) {
```

to this:

```
while (i < document.getElementsByClassName("gun-check").length) {
```

---

Also, as @HuyNguyen pointed out in the comments, when checking the boolean value of `document.getElementsByClassName("gun-check")[i].checked`, you should be checking it against `true` (a boolean), not `"true"` (a string).

Comment: @TendralT. If this helped you, feel free to accept it! :)

Comment: @TendelT. If you feel this answer helped solved your issue, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This will help the community to keep the focus on unanswered questions.